# Example of a metric space

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

What could be an example of a metric space and two balls where the ball with smaller radius contains the ball with larger radius and they don't coincide?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider $X=[0,\infty)$ and $B_4(0)\subsetneq B_3(2)$.

Answer (score 2):

Take $X=\{0,2,6\}\subset \mathbb R$.
Then $B(6,5)=(1,11)\cap X=\{2,6\}$ and $B(2,4.5)=(-2.5,6.5)\cap X=\{0,2,6\}$.

Here $B(x,r)=(x-r,x+r)$ - Ball centered at $x$ with radius $r$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we have a metric space $X$ with points $x,y\in X$ and balls $B_x=B(x,\varepsilon),B_y=B(y,\varepsilon')$, $\varepsilon'<\varepsilon$, and $B_y\supsetneq B_x$. Then there's $z\in X$ with $d(z,y)<\varepsilon'$ but $d(z,x)\geq \varepsilon$, while we know $d(x,y)<\varepsilon'$ since $x\in B_x\subset B_y$. By the triangle inequality we must have $d(z,x)\leq d(z,y)+d(x,y),$ so in particular $\varepsilon< 2\varepsilon'$.

Try a three-point space with $d(x,y)=d(y,z)=1/2,d(x,z)=1$. Then $B(y,3/5)=\{x,y,z\}\supsetneq B(x,5/8)=\{x,y\}$.